# Draw text at center of polygons

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I get an array of polygons from a database. Each shape may be a triangle, a rectangle, a square, or any polygon.

I want to draw text at the center of each polygon. Font size must be dynamic according to the size of each polygon. Text color should match the line color.

Example from database:

[image: colored polygons]

Here is my code:

```js
var polygons = [
  {
    text: "ROI",    color: "#00ff00",
    jointLength: 5,    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [890, 893, 409, 21, 27],    Y: [658, 205, 199, 556, 659],
  },  {
    text: "Lane 3",    color: "#ff0000",
    jointLength: 4,    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [915, 911, 643, 879],    Y: [5, 682, 683, 2],
  },  {
    text: "Lane 4",    color: "#ff0000",
    jointLength: 4,    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [888, 656, 170, 701],    Y: [2, 680, 682, 1],
  },  {
    text: "Lane 5",    color: "#ff0000",
    jointLength: 5,    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [712, 182, 4, 4, 590],    Y: [1, 681, 682, 532, 1],
  },  {
    text: "Speed",    color: "#0000ff",
    jointLength: 4,    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [290, 911, 873, 5],    Y: [367, 357, 668, 664],
  }
];

polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle = polygon.color;
  ctx.lineWidth = polygon.lineWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(polygon.X[0], polygon.Y[0]);
  for (let i = 1; i < polygon.jointLength; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(polygon.X[i], polygon.Y[i]);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=999 height=999></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the array of polygons?

Comment: Which [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_(geometry))?

Comment: It does not matter which center, Circumscribed or Centroid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation of main logic:

- The center of polygon I calculated by the formula of the arithmetic mean
- The size of font I calculated by getting the width of text with `font-size = 300` (but you can change the first check size as you want) and then check if [text with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) is more than the smallest distance between 2 nearest dots (I think that this is good limit if text will be at the center of polygon). If yes then I start to find correct `font-size` with binary search algorithm

Because of this logic the text in second polygon is smaller than it can be because we have 2 dots at the top which are very close to each other

There is a code (open in full page for better visibility):

```js
const polygons = [
  {
    text: "ROI",
    color: "red",
    jointLength: 5,
    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [890, 893, 409, 21, 27],
    Y: [658, 205, 199, 556, 659],
  },
  {
    text: "Lane 3",
    color: "blue",
    jointLength: 4,
    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [915, 911, 643, 879],
    Y: [5, 682, 683, 2],
  },
  {
    text: "Lane 4",
    color: "green",
    jointLength: 4,
    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [888, 656, 170, 701],
    Y: [2, 680, 682, 1],
  },
  {
    text: "Lane 5",
    color: "orange",
    jointLength: 5,
    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [712, 182, 4, 4, 590],
    Y: [1, 681, 682, 532, 1],
  },
  {
    text: "Speed",
    color: "purple",
    jointLength: 4,
    lineWidth: 3,
    X: [290, 911, 873, 5],
    Y: [367, 357, 668, 664],
  },
];

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 1000;

class Polygon {
  #ctx;
  #dots = [];
  #text;
  #color;
  #lineWidth;
  #dotsCount;
  
  constructor(ctx, data) {
    this.#ctx = ctx;
    this.#text = data.text;
    this.#color = data.color;
    this.#lineWidth = data.lineWidth;
    this.#dotsCount = data.jointLength;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#dotsCount; ++ i) {
      this.#dots.push({x: data.X[i], y: data.Y[i]})
    }
  }
  
  #getCenterCoords() {
    const x = this.#dots.reduce((sum, dot) => sum += dot.x, 0) / this.#dotsCount;
    const y = this.#dots.reduce((sum, dot) => sum += dot.y, 0) / this.#dotsCount;
    
    return {x, y};
  }
  
  #distance = (dot1, dot2) => Math.sqrt((dot1.x - dot2.x) ** 2 + (dot1.y - dot2.y) ** 2);
  
  #getMinimalDistanceBetweenDots() {
    let minDist = Infinity;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#dotsCount; ++i) {
      const dot1 = this.#dots[i];
      
      for (let j = i + 1; j < this.#dotsCount; ++j) {
        const dot2 = this.#dots[j];
        const dist = this.#distance(dot1, dot2);
        
        if (dist < minDist) minDist = dist;
      }
    }
    
    return minDist;
  }
  
  #getTextSize() {
    const minAvailableWidth = this.#getMinimalDistanceBetweenDots();
    
    let rightBound = 300;
    let leftBound = 0;
    let fontSize = rightBound;

    while (rightBound - leftBound > 1) {
    
      fontSize = Math.round((leftBound + rightBound) / 2);
      this.#ctx.font = `${fontSize}px verdana`;
      const textSize = this.#ctx.measureText(this.#text).width;
      
      if (textSize > minAvailableWidth) {
        rightBound = fontSize;
        continue;
      }
      
      if (textSize < minAvailableWidth) {
        leftBound = fontSize;
        continue;
      }
      
      if (textSize === minAvailableWidth) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    return fontSize;
  }
  
  draw() {
    const path = new Path2D();
    const firstDot = this.#dots[0];
    const center = this.#getCenterCoords();
  
    this.#dots.forEach(dot => path.lineTo(dot.x, dot.y));

    path.lineTo(firstDot.x, firstDot.y);

    this.#ctx.strokeStyle = this.#color;
    this.#ctx.lineWidth = this.#lineWidth;
    this.#ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.#ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.#ctx.stroke(path);
    
    this.#ctx.font = `${this.#getTextSize()}px verdana`;
    this.#ctx.fillStyle = this.#color;
    this.#ctx.textAlign = 'center'; 
    this.#ctx.fillText(this.#text, center.x, center.y);
  }
}

polygons.forEach((polygon) => new Polygon(ctx, polygon).draw());
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Strange behaviour on the font... at first sight the ROI font should be as big as Speed

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yes I know. It is the problem which I described for second (blue) polygon. But I don't know the best choice of limit of text in any polygon. If you know better solution please share :) I will be glad to learn something new)

Comment: This is perfectly fine (+10) answer for the question, the OP did not even attempt to draw text ... but good to point out that the minAvailableWidth should be calculated on the section where the text will be draw we can see on `Lane 3` the polygon is narrow on top and the text is very small because of that, also the loop to determine the fontsize is a brute force approach it could be significantly improved with a binary search

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I tried to implement your advices. Is it better now?)

Comment: Yes I see the new `getTextSize` that is an awesome improvement

Comment: @EzioMercer Thank you for the answer, But I think the size of the text is highly dependent on the upper side. Can't fix this?

Comment: @Fakhamatia As I said, the size depends on the minimum distance between two adjacent points not the upper side. Unfortunately at this moment it is the my best solution :(

Comment: @EzioMercer What if font size depends on distance between 2 lines on center of polygon? https://imgur.com/a/97cqzvt

Comment: @Fakhamatia Sure it would be better. But I couldn't come up with an algorithm for this. You can rewrite the `getMinimalDistanceBetweenDots` method if you can find a better algorithm. If I can invent an algorithm, I'll update my answer! But this method is also not 100% correct, because if you have a narrow but long rectangle, then the font size will be large and it will go beyond the horizontal boundaries. It can also happen that the middle line mentally drawn vertically will have more than 2 intersections with the polygon and then it is not very clear how to calculate the font size